# Skype for Business Presence is not working on IE Edge and latest versions of chrome and mozilla. (SharePoint Online-Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online

Presence is not working for IE Edge. All latest browser versions are not showing the user presence in SharePoint online - contact details webpart or even through any script like the one at

- https://splyncpresence.codeplex.com/
- or something like at http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/lync-presence-indicators-code-snippets-in-sharepoint-2013/

is not showing the presence. It always shows offline irrespective of user presence on skype and everything works fine on IE 11.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Santosh

Answer (score 1):

There isn't going to be anything we can do about this. it is a known issue. Your work around is to use IE11.

It is documented in the following KB, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3083635:

> The following features or buttons that use ActiveX don’t work with
>   Edge:
>
> The Skype for Business Online (formerly Lync Online)
>   presence indicator
>
> (It doesn't indicate presence, and the contact card doesn't appear.)

Comment: But it is not working on Chrome and Mozilla. And even on IE11, it works only when user is logged into Skype on the same machine. Strange but true.